# DSP method to detect specific frequency which may not be the most dominant in the current sound

Tags: math, audio, signal-processing, fft, core-audio

I'm trying to determine the best DSP method for what I'm trying to accomplish, which is the following:

In real-time, detect the presence of a frequency from a set of different predefined frequencies (no more than 40 different frequencies all within a 1000Hz range). I need to be able to do this even when there are other frequencies (outside of this set or range) that are more dominant.

It is my understanding that FFT might not be the best method for this, because it tells you the most dominant frequency (magnitude) at any given time. This seems like it wouldn't work because if I'm trying to detect say a frequency at 1650Hz (which is present), but there's also a frequency at 500Hz which is stronger, then it's not going to tell me the current frequency is 1650Hz.

I've heard that maybe the Goertzel algorithm might be better for what I'm trying to do, which is to detect single frequencies or a set of frequencies in real-time, even within sounds that have more dominant frequencies than the ones trying to be detected .

Any guidance is greatly appreciated and please correct me if I'm wrong on these assumptions. Thanks!

Comment: A basic theorem of communication theory implies that if there is sufficient noise, you may need to slow down the data rate and use error correction codes for reliable data.

Comment: An FFT is mostly about the non-dominant frequencies, often N-2 out of all N FFT result bins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In vague and somewhat inaccurate terms, the output of the FFT is the magnitude and phase of all[1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/12407/what-is-the-relation-between-fft-length-and-frequency-resolution) frequencies. That is, your statement, "[The FFT] tells you the most dominant frequency (magnitude) at any given time" is incorrect. The FFT is often used as a first step to determine the most dominant frequency, but that's not what it does. In fact, if you are interested in the most dominant frequency, you need to take extra steps over and beyond the FFT: you take the magnitude of all frequencies output by the FFT, and then find the maximum. The corresponding frequency is the dominant frequency.

For your application as I understand it, the FFT is the correct algorithm.

The Goertzel algorithm is closely related to the FFT. It allows for some optimization over the FFT if you are only interested in the magnitude and/or phase of a small subset of frequencies. It might be the right choice for your application depending on the number of frequencies in question, but only as an optimization -- other than performance, it won't solve any problems the FFT won't solve. Because there is more written about the FFT, I suggest you start there and use the Goertzel algorithm only if the FFT proves to not be fast enough and you can establish the Goertzel will be faster in your case.

[1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/12407/what-is-the-relation-between-fft-length-and-frequency-resolution) For practical purposes, what's most inaccurate about this statement is that the frequencies are grouped together in "bins". There's a limited resolution to the analysis which depends on a variety of factors. "bins" and their resolutiom is very nicely explained [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/12407/what-is-the-relation-between-fft-length-and-frequency-resolution).

Comment: In addition, you might want to consider time-domain filters, but it depends on how you plan to detect your frequencies: do you need really low latency, how close are the potential noise frequencies vs the frequencies you are trying to detect, etc. The FFT is the standard method for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you Bjorn for the explanation. I've implemented FFT, and my frequencies that I want to detect are high frequencies above 18000Hz. I'm getting the magnitude and the dominant frequency, but the noise frequencies (such as just human speech or other background noise) sometimes causes the detection of the higher frequencies to be thwarted since the lower frequencies are more dominant at that moment. Any idea on how I can apply a filter for the FFT to maybe block out all frequencies below 18000Hz?

Comment: As far as latency, I need to be able to detect potentially up to 10 to 15 different frequencies within a few seconds.

Comment: It sounds like the real problem is that you don't have true separation between your signal and your noise. You may want to add some error correction or just some simple modulation to your signal. I suggest asking on DSP.stackexchange.com and including more detail about your signal, noise, what you are using as transievers and so on.

Comment: Do you think creating a high pass filter that filters out frequencies below 18000hz would help?

Comment: You shouldnt be looking at data below 18kHz, so it shouldn't make any difference. It might reduce some edge effects or other problems, so you could try it, but don't expect any miracles. If it does help, it probably indicates you've done something else wrong.

Comment: Maybe this will help with the basics: http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/07/frequency-detection-using-fft-aka-pitch.html

Comment: This answer is correct.  Either Goertzel or FFT can give you the correct answer, and it will be a toss-up as to which one is faster.

Answer (score 0):

I am leaving my other answer as-is because I think it stands on it's own.

Based on your comments and private email, the problem you are facing is most likely this: sounds, like speech, that are principally in one frequency range, have harmonics that stretch into higher frequency ranges. This problem is exacerbated by low quality microphones and electronics, but it is not caused by them and wouldn't go away even with perfect equipment. Once your signal is cluttered with noise in the same band, you can't really distinguish **on** from **off** in a simple and reliable way, because **on** could be caused by the noise. You could try to do some adaptive thresholding based on noise in other bands, and you'll probably get somewhere, but that's no way to build a robust system.

There are a number of ways to solve this problem, but they all involve modulating your signal and using error detection and correction. Basically, you are building a modem and/or radio. Ultimately, what I'm saying is this: you can't solve your problem on the detector alone. You need to build some redundancy into your signal, and you may need to think about other methods of detection. I know of three methods of sending complex signals:

- Amplitude modulation, which is what it sounds like you are doing now.
- Frequency modulation, which tends to be more robust in the face of ambient noise. (compare FM and AM radio)
- Phase modulation, which is more subtle and tricky.

These methods can be combined and multiplexed in various ways. Read about them on wikipedia. Moreover, once your base signal is transmitted, you can add error correction and detection on top.

I am not an expert in this area, but off the top of my head, I am not sure you'll be able to use PM silently, and AM is simply too sensitive to noise, as you've discovered, although it might work with the right kind of redundancy. FM is probably your best bet.